# Keeping cookies between outbound HTTP calls

Tags: mule

I've got a Mule application that listens for requests from one application, then responds by calling a JSON API multiple times to authenticate and then retrieve several data, doing some transformation, and returning the results.  The API requires HTTP basic authentication.  When an account authenticates, the application that provides the API 1) returns a session/authentication cookie that can be used to identify the current user in subsequent calls, and 2) updates the database to record the last authentication timestamp for the current user.  The API also has a call to check to see if the session/authentication cookie is still valid.

I currently have a flow that invokes the authentication method, then goes on to make a bunch of calls with the session/authentication cookie.

The issue is when the Mule application gets many requests at once, the application that provides the API deadlocks trying to update the authentication timestamp, since the flow will authenticate once for each request.  Is there a way (possibly using the object store) to store the session/authentication cookie for use by subsequent requests to the Mule flow?  Basically, I want the flow to suspend all other requests to the same flow, check to see if there are stored cookies, check to see if they are still valid, authenticate (again or for the first time) to get a new session/authentication cookie if needed, store the new cookie, then continue.

Is that a reasonable way of doing that, and is it even possible?  If not, I think you can get the gist of what I'm trying to accomplish.  What better way is there?  Thanks!

**edit**: I've done a little experimentation, and I can definitely use the object store to hold on to the cookie.  The part I'm stuck on now is how I get the only first request to re-authenticate if there is no valid cookie while any near-simultaneous requests wait.  I'm looking into VM queues and the Mule Requester, but I'm not sure that that will work.  I will post the code for a fully functional test when I'm done.

Comment: Why do you use the plural for "cookies"? Isn't having a single valid cookie enough? Can't a single valid cookie be shared by all threads doing the remote HTTP calls?

Comment: I use the plural for cookies because the authenticated session is identified by two cookies, though I see how that can be confusing in the context of this question.  I have edited the question to talk about a single cookie, because in practice it's the same regardless of how many cookies are needed to identify an authenticated session.  So, **yes**, a single valid cookie is enough, and a single valid cookie being shared by all threads doing the remote HTTP calls is exactly what I want to do.